# Not able to get values of postman global variable

Tags: node.js, postman, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase

I am able to set global variable but unable to get that.

```
pm.sendRequest(getLibraries, function (err, response) {
    if(!err){
        var jsonData = response.json();
        console.log('Libraries: ',jsonData);
        var lib_id = jsonData.contents[0].id;
        console.log('Lib_id:', lib_id);
        pm.globals.set("MLSLibrary_id", lib_id);
    }
});
var library_id = pm.globals.get("MLSLibrary_id"); 
console.log('MLSLibrary_id: ', library_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `pm.sendRequest` is asynchronous. Your request gets executed after you retrieve the global variable. If you want to execute something after the request do it in the if:

```js
pm.sendRequest(getLibraries, function (err, response) {
    if(!err){
        var jsonData = response.json();
        console.log('Libraries: ',jsonData);
        var lib_id = jsonData.contents[0].id;
        console.log('Lib_id:', lib_id);

        // Execute your code with lib_id here
    }
});
```